# Is brave browser halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam, my friends and I are looking for ways to earn extra money and he recommended brave broweser which is a crypto browser that is attached to your chrome. It allows you to earn passive income whilst you browse. I just want to know whether or not this is halal?

Comment: Whether or not this is halal i really don’t recommend it because Brave have a commission for every bitcoin you mine and you need a very powerful computer to mine a lot. You will need hundreds of hours just for some dollars or cents, it would be better to do something in fiverr (it’s halal but not passive income).

Comment: Jzk I’m not looking to mine all the time but my friends and myself are looking for ways to earn a little bit of money and he suggested the idea and said it isn’t much but it’s something that can help. But to confirm is it halal or not?

Comment: I think most scholars say it’s haram, so i think you better not do it just in case it’s haram(and it’s not even worth it)

Comment: Ok jzk for the answer :)